# Solve the initial value problem for the following: $y' - 3y = e^{2x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve for the initial value problem on the specified interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$, and would really appreciate some feedback on my approach.

$y' - 3y = e^{2x}$

with y = 0 when x = 0

I'm following this structure:

$y' + P(x)y = Q(x)$ which is given by the following formula:

$f(x)=be^{-A(x)}+e^{-A(x)}\int_{a}^{x}Q(t)e^{A(t)}dt$

Here I have placed P(x) = 3; Q(x) =$e^{2x}$

expressing all solutions in terms of the initial value at the point a = 0 s.t. f(0) = b

A(x) = $\int_{0}^{x} P(x) dx = \int_{0}^{x}3dx = 3x $

Here we have: $e^{-A(x)} = e^{-3x}$ and $e^{A(x)} = e^{3x}$

Hence, placing this into the formula above:
$f(x) = be^{-3x}+e^{-3x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{2x}e^{3x}=be^{-3x}+e^{-3x} \int_0^xe^{5x}$
$= be^{-3x}+\frac{e^{-3x}}{5}(e^{5x}-e^0)$
$=be^{-3x}+\frac{e^{-3x}e^{5x}}{5}-\frac{e^{-3x}-e^0}{5} = be^{-3x}+\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-3x}+1}{5}$

Comment: This is a linear DE, just multiply by integrating factor on both side i.e. $\int 3dx$

Comment: @VyomYadav after looking back at the question, I have noticed it only asked for the initial value problem; although, I seem to have tried working out the solution. Though, I guess the solution to this is also what I'm after

Comment: I don't get the problem, you are finding a general solution for the equation ( in the interval R ) then why not simply multiply both by I.F.

Comment: @VyomYadav I'm trying to following the methodology given in Tom apostols calculus I, to derive my answers, though I'm unsure. Perhaps you could show me your working?

Comment: $P(x)=-3$ not plus three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach, is to eliminate the exponential term by putting
$$y=ze^{2x}$$

So,
$$y'=(z'+2z)e^{2x}.$$

the equation becomes
$$z'+2z-3z=z'-z=1$$

with
$ z=-1 $ as a particular solution.

thus
$$\color{red}{z}=\lambda e^x-1$$
and
$$y=\color{red}{ z}e^{2x}=\lambda e^{3x}-e^{2x}$$

$$\boxed{y(0)=0\implies y=e^{3x}-e^{2x}}$$

Comment: I'm uncertain with the equation $z'+2x-3z = z'-z = 1$; How exactly did you get $-3z$? furthermore, where did the exponential function go?

Comment: @Meilton I just replaced $ y $ by $ze^{2x}$ and $ y'$ by $(z'+2z)e^{2x}$

Comment: Aha! I understand this now, it relates to $y' - 3y$. Although, when I follow this onto $z = \lambda e^x-1$ I'm not sure how you got the exponential function?

Comment: Without RHS, the homogenous equation $ z'-z=0$ has the solution $ z=\lambda e^x$ to which you add the particular solution $ -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Method with integrating factor $\int_{ }^{ }-3dx$, so $e^{\int-3dx}=e^{-3x}$

Multiply both sides by $e^{-3x}$ to give

$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{-3x}-3e^{-3x}y=e^{-x}$$

The LHS is simply the product rule

$$\int \:\frac{d}{dx}\left(ye^{-3x}\right)dx=\int \:e^{-x}dx$$

which simplifies to $$y=Ce^{3x}-e^{2x}$$

where $C$ is a constant.

Then from the condition, $C=1$

So finally we have  $$y=e^{3x}-e^{2x}$$

Comment: How did you simplify the integral? I cannot seem to get the same answer as you.

Comment: LHS or RHS? Surely you know how to integrate the exponential function. The LHS is simply $ye^{-3x}$ after integration because integration and differentiation are inverse operations.